# How to reuse cached value in ProjectReactor

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

I would like my server to call the login endpoint of another server and cache the auth token for later use. My issue is that when the server tries to reuse the existing token it hangs indefinitely or infinite loops.

```
@Component
class ApiWebClient {

    private var authToken = Mono.just(AuthToken("", Instant.ofEpochSecond(0)))

    fun login(): Mono<AuthToken> {
        authToken = doesTokenNeedRefreshing().flatMap { needsRefreshing ->
            if (needsRefreshing) {
                WebClient.create().post()
                    .uri("https://example.com/login")
                    .body(
                        Mono.just("Credentials"),
                        String::class.java
                    ).exchangeToMono { response ->
                        response.bodyToMono<LoginResponse>()
                    }.map { response ->
                        LOGGER.info("Successfully logged in")
                        AuthToken(response.token, Instant.now())
                    }
            } else {
                LOGGER.info("Reuse token")
                authToken
            }
        }.cache()

        return authToken
    }

    private fun doesTokenNeedRefreshing(): Mono<Boolean> {
        return authToken.map {
            Instant.now().minusMillis(ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLIS).isAfter(it.lastModified)
        }
    }


    class AuthToken(
        var token: String,
        var lastModified: Instant
    )

    companion object {
        private const val ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLIS = 60 * 1000L

        @Suppress("JAVA_CLASS_ON_COMPANION")
        @JvmStatic
        private val LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass.enclosingClass)
    }
}
```

If login gets called twice within the `ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLIS` amount of time then it just hangs. I suspect this is because the `doesTokenNeedRefreshing()` calls a `.map {}` on `authToken` and then later down the chain `authToken` is reassigned to itself. As well, there's an attempt to recache that exact same value. I've played around with recreating `AuthToken` each time instead of returning the same instance but no luck. The server either hangs or infinite loops.

How can I achieve returning the same instance of the cached value so I don't have to make a web request each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for was a `switchIfEmpty` statement to return the existing cached value if it doesn't need to be refreshed.

```
@Component
class ApiWebClient {

    private var authToken = Mono.just(AuthToken("", Instant.ofEpochSecond(0)))

    fun login(): Mono<AuthToken> {
        authToken = doesTokenNeedRefreshing().flatMap { needsRefreshing ->
            if (needsRefreshing) {
                WebClient.create().post()
                    .uri("https://example.com/login")
                    .body(
                        Mono.just("Credentials"),
                        String::class.java
                    ).exchangeToMono { response ->
                        response.bodyToMono<LoginResponse>()
                    }.map { response ->
                        LOGGER.info("Successfully logged in")
                        AuthToken(response.token, Instant.now())
                    }
            } else {
                LOGGER.info("Reuse token")
                Mono.empty()
            }
        }.cache()
            .switchIfEmpty(authToken)

        return authToken
    }
}
```

In this example, if the token doesn't need to be refreshed then the stream returns an empty `Mono`. Then the `switchIfEmpty` statement returns the original auth token. This, therefore, avoids "recursively" returning the same stream over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction` from Spring Security that you could customize to satisfy your needs. In this case token will be updated automatically behind the scene.

If you are looking for "manual" approach, you just need to combine 2 requests.

```
public Mono<String> getResourceWithToken() {
    return getToken()
            .flatMap(token -> getResource(token));
}

private Mono<String> getResource(String authToken) {
        return client.get()
                .uri("/resource")
                .headers(h -> h.setBearerAuth(authToken))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);
}

private Mono<String> getToken() {
        return client.post()
                .uri("/oauth/token")
                .header("Authorization", "Basic " + {CREDS})
                .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("grant_type", "client_credentials"))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(JsonNode.class)
                .map(tokenResponse ->
                    tokenResponse.get("access_token").textValue()
                );
}
```

In this case you will always execute 2 requests and get token for every resource request. Usually token has expiration and you could save some requests by caching `getToken()` `Mono`.

```
private Mono<String> tokenRequest = getToken().cache(Duration.ofMinutes(30));

public Mono<String> getResourceWithToken() {
    return tokenRequest
            .flatMap(token -> getResource(token));
}
```